# Dropzone.JS send files and form data in the same request

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js within my existing form to store images, am i able to store the images at the same time i save the form ? I mean, send the images dropped on the dropzone on the same request as the form ?

```
     {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'ajaxaddevent','url' => 
'/savenewevent', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Título do Evento</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-
control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventtype">Tipo</label>
                    <select class="form-control selecttype" name="eventtype" id="eventtype">
                        @foreach ($eventtypes as $eventtype)
                            <option value="{{ $eventtype->id }}" > {{ $eventtype->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventsubtype">Sub-tipo</label>
                    <select class="form-control selectsubtypes" name="eventsubtype" id="eventsubtype">
                        @foreach ($eventsubtypes as $eventsubtype)
                            <option value="{{ $eventsubtype->id }}" > {{ $eventsubtype->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="eventsubtype">Temas</label>
                    <span class="interest_text">podes escolher mais que um</span>
                    <div class="interests_list submit_event">
                            @foreach ($themes as $theme)                    
                                <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="theme{{ $theme->id }}" name="themes[]" value="{{ $theme->id }}"/>
                                    <label for="theme{{ $theme->id }}"><span></span>{{ $theme->name }}</label>
                                </div>   
                            @endforeach  
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="startdate">Data</label>
                        <input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" class="form-control" data-country="PT" placeholder="Início">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="enddate">&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" class="form-control" data-country="PT" placeholder="Fim">
                        <span id="adddata" class="adddata">Adicionar mais horas</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="schedule_start">Horário</label>
                        <input type="date" id="schedule_start" name="schedule_start" class="form-control" data-country="PT" placeholder="Início">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="schedule_end">&nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="date" id="schedule_end" name="schedule_end" class="form-control" data-country="PT" placeholder="Fim">
                        <span id="addschedule" class="addschedule">Adicionar mais horas</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="duration">Duração</label>
                    <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreve apenas números" />
                    <div class="duration_tips">
                        <input type="radio" id="duration_tips_hours" name="duration_tips[]" value="hours" /><label for="duration_tips_hours"><span></span>Horas</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="duration_tips_weeks" name="duration_tips[]" value="weeks" /><label for="duration_tips_weeks"><span></span>Semanas</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="duration_tips_days" name="duration_tips[]" value="days" /><label for="duration_tips_days"><span></span>Dias</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="duration_tips_months" name="duration_tips[]" value="months" /><label for="duration_tips_months"><span></span>Meses</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="available">Número de vagas</label>
                    <input type="text" id="available" name="available" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreve apenas números" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="price">Preço</label>
                    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreve apenas números" />
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telemovel">Telemóvel</label>
                    <input type="text" id="telemovel" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="distrito">Distrito / região</label>
                    <select class="form-control selectdistrict" name="districtID" id="districtID">
                        @foreach ($districts as $district)
                            <option value="{{ $district->id }}" > {{ $district->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="concelho">Concelho</label>
                    <select class="form-control selectcounties" name="countyID" id="countyID">
                        @foreach ($counties as $county)
                            <option value="{{ $county->id }}" > {{ $county->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="morada">Morada</label>
                    <input type="text" id="morada" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="freguesia">Freguesia</label>
                        <input type="text" name="parish" id="parish" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="cod_postal">Código Postal</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cod_postal" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="website">Website</label>
                    <input type="text" id="website" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="facebook">Facebook</label>
                    <input type="text" name="facebooklink" id="facebook" class="form-control" placeholder="www.facebook.com/" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
                    <textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control descricao_anunciante" placeholder="(quem és, o que fazes ou o que representas, temas e tipos de eventos)"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"> </div>

                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GUARDAR DADOS</button>
                {{Form::close()}}
```

**JS**

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
        url: '/savenewevent',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 5,
        maxFilesize: 1,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        init: function() {
            dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

            // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
            document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("name", jQuery("#name").val());
                formData.append("eventtype", jQuery("#eventtype").val());
                formData.append("eventtype", jQuery("#eventtype").val());
                formData.append("eventsubtype", jQuery("#eventsubtype").val());
                formData.append("startdate", jQuery("#startdate").val());
                formData.append("enddate", jQuery("#enddate").val());
                formData.append("schedule_start", jQuery("#schedule_start").val());
                formData.append("schedule_end", jQuery("#schedule_end").val());
                formData.append("available", jQuery("#available").val());
                formData.append("price", jQuery("#price").val());
                formData.append("email", jQuery("#email").val());
                formData.append("telemovel", jQuery("#telemovel").val());
                formData.append("districtID", jQuery("#districtID").val());
                formData.append("morada", jQuery("#morada").val());
                formData.append("cod_postal", jQuery("#cod_postal").val());
                formData.append("website", jQuery("#website").val());
                formData.append("facebook", jQuery("#facebook").val());
                formData.append("description", jQuery("#description").val());
            });
        }
```

- Send the images/files on the same request (i did a var_dump when i click on submit and the files from the dropzone arent there), how can i achieve that ?

**OR**

my objective is to store a serialized array on database with the filenames, so if theres another alternative to do that, its okay.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by var_dump? What are you using on the server side?

Comment: Laravel 5.4, PHP

Comment: As far as I can see, all seems correct, the files and the form data should appear on the server side all on the same request, I don't know how laravel works but for pure php the files should be in `$_FILES` and the form data in `$_POST`

Comment: if i do print_r($_FILES); it shows me a empty array.

Comment: Does the page reloads when you submit the form? If Yes try one simple thing, move the dropzone div and the button outside the form, and see if now the files and the data appear in the request.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can make your dropzone **autoProcessQueue** as true then, return the filename as response once its uploaded and store it in the form input.

```
this.on("success", function (file, response) {
    $('#hidden_input_id').val(response);
}
```

when you are submitting the form, you will get the filenames from name of **#hidden_input_id** and store that name into database.

Note: Dropzone ajax/image upload url and the form submission url should be different.

the sample code looks like, 
html

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'ajaxaddevent','url' => 
'/savenewevent', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) }}

<input id="hidden_image_name" name="hidden_image_name"

<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"> </div>

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GUARDAR DADOS</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

and the script like,

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: '/uploadimage',
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        this.on("success", function (file, response) {
            $('#hidden_image_name').val(response);
        }

    }
};
```

**/uploadimage** route should return the name of the uploaded image file.

In **/savenewevent** route you can check the posted params and if the **hidden_image_name** is not empty map that image name to that event.

Comment: Thank you, i understood. But i dont know how the 'Note' part, how can i use two different urls ? Can you give an example with code ?